# ElasticSearch: How to update a document type in an existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, types, updates

Long story short:

I have created a strict template, created several daily indices and changes one of the document types (**%_level** type from *float* to *integer*) in the template.

After that, I've created the rest of the daily indices.

**The problem:**

I need to change the document type (**%_level** type from *float* to *integer*) in the old indices to be compatible with the new indices.
How can I do this?

Now for the details...

I have the following strict template:

```
PUT _template/example-template
{
    "order":0,
    "version":200,
    "index_patterns":["example-*"],
    "settings":{
        "index":{
            "number_of_shards":4
         }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "iterations": {
            "dynamic":"strict",
            "properties": {
                "%_average1": {
                    "type":"float"
                },
                "%_average2": {
                    "type":"float"
                },
                "sum": {
                    "type":"integer"
                },
                "%_level": {
                    "type":"float"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Several indices were created with this template.

- example-20191220
- example-20191221
- example-20191222
- example-20191223

After a while I've realised that we need to change **%_level** type from *float* to *integer*, so I have changed the template into the following:

```
PUT _template/example-template
{
    "order":0,
    "version":200,
    "index_patterns":["example-*"],
    "settings":{
        "index":{
            "number_of_shards":4
         }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "iterations": {
            "dynamic":"strict",
            "properties": {
                "%_average1": {
                    "type":"float"
                },
                "%_average2": {
                    "type":"float"
                },
                "sum": {
                    "type":"integer"
                },
                "%_level": {
                    "type":"integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the the following indices were created where **%_level** type is an *integer*.

- example-20192412
- example-20192512
- example-20192612

But the old indices contains indices with **%_level** that is *float* and the new indices are with **%_level** that is an *integer*.

I needed to convert the old indices **%_level** from *float* to *integer* so I can build a report with all the indices.

How can I change the **%_level** in the old indices from *float* to *integer*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can add and remove document names from an exisitng index by providing the document ID, it is problematic to do so if you want to update the document type, and to apply it on all the index document.

A good solution for this problem will be reindex.

> **Important:**
>
> The reindex process can convert some types implicitly ([Numeric Type Casting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-casting.html#numeric-type-casting)) and the others explicitly.
>
> In case you need implicit conversion, you can skip section 2

Meaning, apply the following over all the old indices (e.g. *example-20191220*):

1. create a new index from **example-20191220** that will be called **example-20191220-new**
2. add a painless script in the creation process that convert **%_level** type from *float* to *integer*
3. delete the old index **example-20191220**
4. reindex **example-20191220-new** into **example-20191220**

Now, the 'updated' index **example-20191220** is with the correct **%_level** type.

The reindex in **section 2** should look like the following:

(it is performed and tested on *Kibana Dev Tools*)

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "example-20191220"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "example-20191220-new"
    },
    "script": {
    "lang": "painless", 
    "source": 
        """
        Double num = ctx._source['%_level'];
        if(num != null)
        { ctx._source['%_level'] = num.intValue(); }
        """
    }
}
```

The reindex in **section 4** should look like the following:

(it is performed and tested on *Kibana Dev Tools*)

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "example-20191220-new"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "example-20191220"
    }
}
```